# Dynamic href with parent directory and current file name

Tags: javascript, href

I have a menu pages that is on every page, and I want the links to have ref of current page and the file folder.

Let say the folder directory is as below

```
root > Folder1> Foldcer2> File.html
```

My current link is something like below

```
<a href="'../../OtherFolder/newpage.html?ref=#'+'Folder1|File.html
<a href="'../../OtherFolder/newpage2.html?ref=#'+'Folder1|File.html
```

How can I make it into something dynamically, where I do not have to change the 'Folder1' in the href on every page.

I manage to get the current page name, but I'm stuck on getting the parent directories and how to add it into a 'href'.

Comment: You should do this server-side where possible.

Comment: Doesn't the Document.referer variable tell you where you came from after you clicked - no need to pass as a parameter

Comment: @Brad, currently I'm only able to do it locally :(

Comment: @ Foloris, I did tried document.referrer, but it returns nothing. or like @brad said, it needs to be done on9?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

```
 <html>
<body>

 The referrer of this document is:
<script>
 document.write(document.referrer);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Pretty sure you can use that to so what you intended?